# How to grep the process of iTunes in Python scripting

Tags: python, itunes, grep, kill

```
import os, signal

def check_kill_process(iTunes):
    for line in os.popen("ps ax | grep " + iTunes + " | grep -v grep"):
        fields = line.split()
        pid = fields[0]
        os.kill(int(pid), signal.SIGKILL)
```

Comment: Take a look at `pgrep`.

Comment: that is instead of grep, to use pgrep right

Comment: yes, this is instead of both `grep`s.

Comment: Still there is not executing, ends in zero error

Comment: I tried this code:: import os os.system('ps -ef | grep iTunes') , now it is grepping the process of iTunes , but dont have idea have to kill the pid by using python script